# Ordinary link to affiliate link

Tags: php, product-list, addtocart

I have had an affiliate extension that allows my store to accept affiliate feeds.

I wish to change the `Add to Bag` text on the category page to open a window that then redirects to the products on the partnered site.

The code for the **category page** is: -

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <div class="add-to-bag grid12-6 no-gutter">
                            <a title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Bag') ?>" href="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('ADD TO BAG') ?></span></span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="more-info grid12-6 no-gutter">
                            <a title="<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('MORE INFO') ?></span></span></a>
                        </div>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock grid-full"><span><?php echo $this->__('OUT OF STOCK') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

The code for **addtocart** (which is what I want for the category page) is: -

```
<?php $flag = $_product->getIsAffiliateProduct() ; ?>
<?php if ($flag ): ?>
<!-- beo affiliate product -->
 <div class="add-to-cart">
<?php $advertiserBuyURL = $_product->getAdvertiserBuyLink(); ?>
    <?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Buy on Store'); ?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="redirectTo('<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'/redirectTo.php?goto='.urlencode($advertiserBuyURL); ?>','<?php print $_product->getAdvertiserID(); ?>')" >
        <span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span>
    </button>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    <?php if($_product->getImpressionUrl() != "" ) : ?>
    <img src="<?php echo$_product->getImpressionUrl(); ?>" width="1" height="1" border="0"/>
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do to achieve this is:

In your template that you posted replace the following lines:

```
<div class="add-to-bag grid12-6 no-gutter">
    <a title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Bag') ?>" href="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('ADD TO BAG') ?></span></span></a>
</div>
```

With the full snippet of text that you provided.

Now I would hope that at a very least you are moving the template files out from base/default into a theme for your project.

Then a more feature rich solution is to then move the entire logic out from the template and into a new block with its own template.. To do this you would need a new module with block that is responsible for isAffiliate. Then in the template file you could call the block. Via XML so add block to `catalog_product_list` and in template `getChildHtml()`

But depending on your skills and time the first solution will work.

Answer (score 1):

$advertiserBuyURL = $_product->getAdvertiserBuyLink(); ?>

```
                            <a title="<?php echo $this->__('Buy Now') ?>" target="_blank" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().'/redirectTo.php?goto='.urlencode($advertiserBuyURL).'&vendor_name='.$advertiser_id; ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('BUY NOW') ?></span></span></a>
```

This worked. I paid a freelancer on oDesk.